# NewtonsotJson dll its not assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I need to read a JSON string in .NET 3.5, then add Newtonsoft.Json.dll. I can use the methods of this dll, but when I compile and run my app send this error:

```
Advertencia 1   La referencia al tipo 'System.DateTimeOffset' indica que está definida en 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\mscorlib.dll', pero no se pudo encontrar    c:\data\dev\C#\GrucasInvApp\GrucasInvApp\Lib\Newtonsoft.Json.dll    GrucasInvApp
Error   2   El tipo 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging' está definido en un ensamblado al que no se hace referencia. Debe agregar una referencia al ensamblado 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. C:\data\dev\C#\GrucasInvApp\GrucasInvApp\GUI\LoginForm.cs   45  21  GrucasInvApp
Error   2   El tipo 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging' está definido en un ensamblado al que no se hace referencia. Debe agregar una referencia al ensamblado 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. C:\data\dev\C#\GrucasInvApp\GrucasInvApp\GUI\LoginForm.cs   45  21  GrucasInvApp
```

When I comment out the lines where I'm using the library, my app works! :C

Comment: go to the property of solution and make it application 3.5

Comment: It looks like you may be building against the wrong version of Json.NET - how have you installed it, and which version are you referencing? (If you use NuGet, I'd expect it to just be fine...)

Comment: Additionally to Jon's comment, note that Json.NET does provide different DLLs for different .NET framework **targets** (as set in your project). That means, Json.NET provides a DLL for .NET 4.5, and it provides another DLL for .NET 3.5, for example.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you added the `Newtonsoft.Json` assembly reference? If you use nuget like Jon said, it should reference the correct dll automatically for your project .Net version. Please avoid using other methods, like manual file references. If you did that, perhaps it would be a good ideia to delete the added reference and re-add it via nuget.